# Changing the language makes the font weight (semibold) go away

Tags: fontspec, bold, polyglossia

Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia,fontspec}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{latin}
\setmainfont{Source Sans Pro}
\newfontfamily\Smbd{Source Sans Pro Semibold}

\begin{document}

1. normal weight  \textit{italic} \textlatin{foreign} blah

2. \textbf{bold   \textit{italic} \textlatin{foreign} blah}

3. {\Smbd{semibold \textit{italic} \textlatin{foreign} blah}}

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

On the line # 3, the word "foreign" is not typesetted with the semibold font. What should I change in the code to achieve this?

*Note:* I would like to use both the bold font and the semibold font in the document.

Comment: Polyglossia issues `\rmfamily` as part of `\textlatin`. Do you need both bold and semibold?

Answer (score 2):

This question came up a few years later on a search, and it’s a good one, so it’s worth answering.

The `polyglossia` package allows you to define fonts for every language and script, such as `\latinfont` and `\germanfont`.  If you don’t declare one for each language, `polyglossia` does *not* assume that whatever font you’ve currently selected can support every langiage, so it will restore the default font family.

Your options include:

### Quick Fix

Set your font family inside your language block.

```
\begin{latin}
\sourcesanspro
Exempli gratia.
\end{latin}
```

You might find it convenient to define something like

```
\newcommand{\latinsf}[1]{\textlatin{\textsf{#1}}}
```

I use this below.

### Add a Semibold Weight with `fontspec`

This is a more complicated solution, but it gets you NFSS-style `\sbseries` and `\textsf{}` commands that will work with multiple fonts.  In this example, I’ll set up Latin Modern Roman as the main font, then a `\sourcesanspro` font family, and set it as the sans-serif font.

```
\documentclass[varwidth, preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setmainfont[
  Scale = 1.0,
  Ligatures ={ Common, Discretionary, TeX},
  FontFace={sb}{n}{Font = {lmromandemi10-regular}, Extension = .otf },
  FontFace={sb}{it}{Font = {lmromandemi10-oblique}, Extension = .otf }
]{Latin Modern Roman}

\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase, Ligatures=TeX}

\newfontfamily{\sourcesanspro}[
  Extension = .otf ,
  Ligatures = {Common, TeX},
  UprightFont = *-Regular ,
  BoldFont = *-Bold ,
  ItalicFont = *-RegularIt ,
  BoldItalicFont = *-BoldIt ,
  FontFace = {sb}{n}{*-Semibold},
  FontFace = {sb}{it}{*-SemiboldIt}
]{SourceSansPro}

\renewcommand{\sffamily}{\sourcesanspro}

% The commands to select semibold weight:
\DeclareRobustCommand{\sbseries}{\fontseries{sb}\selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textsb}{\sbseries}

\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{latin}

\newcommand{\latinsf}[1]{\textlatin{\textsf{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\sffamily
1. normal weight  \textit{italic} \latinsf{foreign} blah

2. \textbf{bold   \textit{italic} \latinsf{foreign} blah}

3. \textsb{semibold \textit{italic} \latinsf{foreign} blah}

4. \textrm{\textsb{Roman Demibold \textit{oblique} \textlatin{foreign} blah}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Use the `sourcesanspro` Package

Unfortunately, this seems to be broken as of August 2018.  If it ever gets fixed, it will be your simplest option.  The package includes a `\sourcesansprolight` font family whose regular weight is Source Sans Pro Light and whose bold weight is Source Sans Pro Semibold.

```
\documentclass[varwidth, preview]{standalone}
\usepackage[default, osf, opentype]{sourcesanspro}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{latin}

\begin{document}

1. normal weight  \textit{italic} \textlatin{foreign} blah

2. \textbf{bold   \textit{italic} \textlatin{foreign} blah}

3. {\sourcesansprolight\textbf{semibold \textit{italic} \textlatin{\sourcesansprolight foreign} blah}}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution: instead of defining a new font family, I can change the main font:

```
\newcommand\Smbd[1]{\setmainfont{Source Sans Pro Semibold}#1\setmainfont{Source Sans Pro}}
```

This is a rather ugly trick, but it does the job.